# Only let function be called as a method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, namespaces

Say I'm writing a module, MyPyLib, that uses another built-in module. From the built-in module, I import a class, Foo. I then define this function, bar:

```
def bar(self):
    return self
```

This function is written to be a method of the Foo class and I can make it behave properly with `setattr(Foo,'bar', bar)`. Then `Foo.bar()` will work as intended. However, anyone who imports MyPyLib can also call `bar` as its own function. Is there any way to limit this function so that `Foo.bar()` works, but `bar(arg)` doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should not care about incorrect use, that's a problem for the caller. Python is a language for *consenting adults*; if someone wants to bend the rules and use `bar` with a different argument, that's their problem, not yours.

If you insist, your only option here is to explicitly test for the type of `self`:

```
def bar(self):
    assert isinstance(self, Foo)
    return self
```

as there is no way for `bar` to detect otherwise that it is being called as a bound method or used unbound.

Comment: Fair enough. The isinstance will be helpful regardless.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (and more usual) approach is to derive a new class from class `Foo` and to define `bar` explicitly as a method of the new class:

```
class FooBar(Foo):
    def bar(self):
        return self
```

This way the intended usage of `bar` is much more clear.

Comment: I don't believe this has the intended effect. You would have to call `FooBar.bar()`, not `Foo.bar()`, correct?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. However your comment seems to indicate that you can't use a subclass `FooBar` instead of the original class `Foo`.  If this is the case, then you have to use monkey-patching as suggested by Martijn Pieters.